# How can I find the longest vector/list within a list in R?

Tags: r

Given the following list:

```
myList<-list(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(5,6,7), c=c(8), d=c(9,1,2,3,4,5))
```

What can I do to find out which element of the list is the longest? I have been trying for loops and if statements, but I keep getting errors about the length being greater than 1 so only the first element was used. I currently do not have any working code for this problem, but what I have tried is:

```
for(i in 1:length(n)){
   if(length(n[[i]])>=max){
      max<-length(n[[i]])
      longest<-names(n[[i]])
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I were to change the list so that a and d had the same lengths, is there a way to alter this to display both names? If not, thank you so much for your help this was perfect!